# Searching for a Key in Multivalue Dictionaries in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, search

I want to set up a lookup table like so:

```
 Key           Value
 -----         ------------------
 Cat           Lion, Tiger, Cheetah
 Fish          Dolphin, Whale
 Dog .         Pitbull, Doberman
```

An input of "Lion" would return the key "Cat"

I have set up 3 possible ways to initialize the data:

A Dictionary:

```
var map = new Dictionary<string,string>
{
    ["Dolphin"] = "Fish",
    ["Lion"] = "Cat",
    //....
};
```

A HashSet:

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>
{
    {"cat", new HashSet<string> {"Lion", "Tiger", "Cheetah"}},
    {"fish", new HashSet<string> {"Dolphin", "Whale"}},
    {"Dog", new HashSet<string> {"Pitbull", "Doberman"}}
};
```

A tuple:

```
var data = new List<Tuple<string, List<string>>>
{
    Tuple.Create<string,List<string>> ("Cat", new List<string> { "Cheetah", "Lion" }), 
    Tuple.Create<string,List<string>> ("Dog", new List<string> { "Doberman", "Pitbull" }), 
    Tuple.Create<string,List<string>> ("Fish", new List<string> { "Dolphin", "Whale" }), 

};
```

Given an animal, I want to return its type. 
I know for the dictionary I can call the `ContainsKey` method.

Is there something similar for the other two options?

The data set isn't that big, (~15 keys that have 10 or so values), so I'm also wondering if one option would be better than the other in terms of performance.

Comment: Isn't it better to make `Lion`, `Cheetah`, ... *keys* of the Dictonary and `Cat`, `Dog`, ... values?

Comment: @Zereges from what I understand in a prior suggestion, dictionaries are better for looking up values by key, not vice versa.

Comment: Dictionaries are better for looking up values by key.

Comment: @lost9123193 No, it's other way around. You have indexer by key, `TryGetValue` by key.

Comment: @Shyju thanks, bad type, that's what i meant

Comment: So keep "Lion" as key and "Cat" as value, "Cheeta" as key  and "Cat" as value.

Comment: Build the dictionary based on how you want to access the data .If you have "Cheetah" and want to get "Cat", do "Cheetah" as key and "Cat" as value. So you get a o(1) lookup (that is what dictionaries are for)

Comment: @Shyju Ok, that makes sense. That's how its currently set up and that's how I would like it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, this architecture is a bit tricky... I mean, normally the lookup is based on keys, not on values, but I understand that sometimes you need to reverse the common logics and retrieve what you need within a data structure that is adequate in many other situations, except that one!

Anyway, if I was given the choice I would go for the `HashSet` approach, since it can grant a uniqueness of its values and also an immediate aggregation of the subtypes. But you can eventually run a benchmark and find out the fastest lookup solution in a few minutes.

Using the aforementioned approach (the `HashSet` one I mean), you can retrieve your type as follows:

```
String animalType = data.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Contains("Dolphin")).Select(p => p.Key).FirstOrDefault();

// Animal type found: Fish!
if (animalType != null)
    Console.WriteLine("Animal type found: " + animalType + "!");
else
    Console.WriteLine("No animal type found!");
```

Answer (score 2):

I am suggesting a bit different approach.

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public string Type { get; }
    public string Name { get; }

    protected Animal(string type, string name)
    {
        Type = type;
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    public Cat(string name) : base("Cat", name)
    {
    }
}

public class Fish : Animal
{
    public Fish(string name) : base("Fish", name)
    {
    }
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Animal> list = new List<Animal>();
        list.Add(new Cat("Cheetah"));
        list.Add(new Fish("Dolphin"));

        var cheetahType = list.FirstOrDefault(animal => animal.Name == "Cheetah")?.Type;
        var doplhinType = list.FirstOrDefault(animal => animal.Name == "Dolphin")?.Type;
    }
}
```

If you don't actually need that much, you can make `Animal` nonabstract and define `enum` instead of `string Type` and remove derived children.

Comment: It's a nice approach, but the OP may not need to shape his data over real classes. He could be just processing twitter speeches or something like this... so he would not need to move outside string processing.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Dictionary<string, string>` option.

```
var animalToType = new Dictionary<string,string>
{
    ["Dolphin"] = "Fish",
    ["Lion"] = "Cat",
    //....
};
var lionType = animalToType["Lion"];
```

The other options are not going to be as simple. They will all involve loops, whether directly or hidden by Linq calls.